# LEFT JOIN with COUNT getting error

Tags: mysql, sql, select, count, left-join

I want to count the entries of a left join mysql but I am getting always an error

```
SELECT g.uid,g.datei, u.id, u.avatar, u.avatarapproved, a.points, COUNT (g.uid) as hits
FROM jos_findme_gallery as g 
LEFT JOIN jos_findme as u ON g.uid= u.user_id 
LEFT JOIN jos_alpha_userpoints as a ON g.uid= a.userid 
WHERE u.avatar IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY g.uid asc
```

> FUNCTION db1140411-dualda.COUNT does not exist. Check the 'Function Name Parsing and Resolution' section in the Reference Manual

Any Ideas?

Comment: You need to group them by g.uid for the COUNT function to work

Comment: would be much easier if you show your table, data, and expected result from the query.

Answer (score 2):

You *should* use a `GROUP BY` when using an aggregate function, but you're getting this specific error because of the space between `COUNT` and `(`.

[From the MySQL Docs:](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/function-resolution.html)

> The requirement that function calls be written with no whitespace
>   between the name and the parenthesis applies only to the built-in
>   functions that have special considerations. `COUNT` is one such name.

To fix this, get rid of the space... and throw in a `GROUP BY` to explicit:

```
SELECT 
  g.uid,
  g.datei, 
  u.id, 
  u.avatar, 
  u.avatarapproved, 
  a.points, 
  COUNT(g.uid) as hits
FROM jos_findme_gallery as g 
LEFT JOIN jos_findme as u ON g.uid= u.user_id 
LEFT JOIN jos_alpha_userpoints as a ON g.uid= a.userid 
WHERE u.avatar IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY 
  g.uid,
  g.datei, 
  u.id, 
  u.avatar, 
  u.avatarapproved, 
  a.points
ORDER BY g.uid asc
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to group by something. COUNT is an aggregate function.

```
SELECT g.uid,g.datei, u.id, u.avatar, u.avatarapproved, a.points, COUNT(1) as hits
...
GROUP BY g.uid
ORDER BY ...
```

Also, why do you have 2 left joins? Which of the 2 joined tables do you want to count rows from?

Comment: [Actually, you don't in MySql.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-extensions.html)  It would also have been a different error message...

Comment: You don't but the result is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

I think there's no space between count and what your counting as we can see in the other examples.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT g.uid, g.datei, u.id, u.avatar, u.avatarapproved, a.points, COUNT(g.uid) AS hits
FROM jos_findme_gallery AS g 
LEFT JOIN jos_findme AS u ON g.uid= u.user_id 
LEFT JOIN jos_alpha_userpoints AS a ON g.uid= a.userid 
WHERE u.avatar IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY u.id
ORDER BY g.uid ASC
```